# Include missing values (NaN) in value counts using dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask

Dask exposes [`dask.dataframe.Series.value_counts`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.Series.value_counts). In contrast to its pandas counterpart ([here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)) the dask implementations seems not to support the parameter `dropna`. Am I missing something? If indeed this is not possible, what would be a canonical workaround?

Comment: If you think that there is a feature that is not yet implemented, then I recommend raising an issue on Github

Comment: It's in the Dask documentation but it does not seem to work. Be careful with group by operations on dask frames. If it includes a na column it will be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

So you can using `DataFrameGroupBy.size`

```
df.groupby('col').size()
```